# error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1 while installing eventlet

Tags: python, ubuntu, eventlet

I wanted to install `eventlet` on my system in order to have "Herd" for software deployment.. but the terminal is showing a gcc error:

```
  root@agrover-OptiPlex-780:~# easy_install -U eventlet
  Searching for eventlet
  Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/eventlet/
  Reading http://wiki.secondlife.com/wiki/Eventlet
  Reading http://eventlet.net
   Best match: eventlet 0.9.16
    Processing eventlet-0.9.16-py2.7.egg
    eventlet 0.9.16 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

   Using /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/eventlet-0.9.16-py2.7.egg
 Processing dependencies for eventlet
 Searching for greenlet>=0.3
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/greenlet/
Reading https://github.com/python-greenlet/greenlet
Reading http://bitbucket.org/ambroff/greenlet
Best match: greenlet 0.3.4
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/g/greenlet/greenlet-   0.3.4.zip#md5=530a69acebbb0d66eb5abd83523d8272
Processing greenlet-0.3.4.zip
Writing /tmp/easy_install-_aeHYm/greenlet-0.3.4/setup.cfg
Running greenlet-0.3.4/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-_aeHYm/greenlet-0.3.4/egg-dist-tmp-t9_gbW
In file included from greenlet.c:5:0:
greenlet.h:8:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1`
```

Why can't `Python.h` be found?

Answer (score 416, accepted):

Your install is failing because you don't have the python development headers installed.

First update the packages with `sudo apt update`.

You can do this through apt on ubuntu/debian with:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

for python3 use:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev
```

For `eventlet` you might also need the `libevent` libraries installed so if you get an error talking about that you can install libevent with:

```
sudo apt-get install libevent-dev
```

Comment: FWIW, you definitely need both python-dev and libevent-dev. Thanks!

Comment: For fedora, you can use: `sudo yum install python-devel`

Comment: I suggest running `sudo apt-get update` before running these 2 commands. I was getting error with `sudo apt-get install python-dev`.

Comment: I have the same error but have python-devel installed and system is updated with yum -y install updates.. what else could the issue be?

Comment: If using Python 2.6: `sudo apt-get install python2.6-dev`

Comment: just went through this problem where python-dev didn't fix it. The problem is there was a separate one for python3, so it'd have `sudo apt-get install python3-dev`

Comment: to remember how to install django104

Comment: not aways it is possible to use root and use apt-get

Comment: yum install python3-devel

Comment: after hours of trying to get `spacy` on centos7, this was the final missing piece. Thanks!

Comment: yum install python-devel worked for me, thanks @Java Xu

Comment: I also had to install gcc
> sudo apt install gcc

Answer (score 59):

For Fedora:

```
sudo yum install python-devel

sudo yum install libevent-devel
```

and finally:

```
sudo easy_install gevent
```

Comment: sudo yum install python-devel

sudo yum install libevent-devel

worked for me

Answer (score 42):

What worked for me on **CentOS** was:

```
sudo yum -y install gcc
sudo yum install python-devel
```

Comment: solved my problem too.    `unable to execute 'gcc': No such file or directory
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1`

Comment: use `sudo yum install python34-devel` for python 3.x as the other is only for python 2.x

Comment: I was looking everywhere for this. Using RHEL 7 and gcc is not included by default anymore.

Answer (score 35):

For **Redhat Versions(Centos 7)** Use the below command to install Python Development Package

***Python 2.7***

```
sudo yum install python-dev
or
sudo yum install python-devel
```

***Python 3.4***

```
sudo yum install python34-devel
```

***Python 3.6***

```
sudo yum install python36-devel
```

If the issue is still not resolved then try installing the below packages -

```
sudo yum install python-devel

sudo yum install openssl-devel

sudo yum install libffi-devel
```

Comment: `No package python-dev available.` I am getting this.

Comment: It should be `python-devel` in CentOS

Answer (score 22):

On **MacOS** I had trouble installing `fbprophet` which requires `pystan` which requires `gcc` to compile. I would consistently get the same error: *command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1*

I think I fixed the problem for myself thus:

I used `brew install gcc` to install the newest version, which ended up being `gcc-8`

Then I made sure that when `gcc` ran it would use `gcc-8` instead.

It either worked because I added `alias gcc='gcc-8` in my `.zshrc` (same as `.bashrc` but for *zsh*), or because I ran `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH` (see [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28982564/5017391))

*Also*: all my attempts were inside a *virtual environment* and I only succeeded by installing `fbprophet` globally (with *pip*), but still no success inside a *venv*

Comment: The most helpful answer! Exporting PATH did the trick

Answer (score 8):

If it is still not working, you can try this

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

in my case, it solved the problem.

Comment: Solved my problem with the `shap` library on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: this solution work with `JPype1` library on python:3.8.13-slim

Answer (score 7):

This is an old post but I just run to the same problem on AWS EC2 installing regex. This working perfectly for me

```
sudo yum -y install gcc
```

and next

```
sudo yum -y install gcc-c++
```

Answer (score 5):

try this :

```
sudo apt-get install libblas-dev libatlas-base-dev
```

I had a similar issue on Ubuntu 14.04. For me the following Ubuntu packages

Answer (score 5):

On **MacOS** I also had problems trying to install `fbprophet` which had `gcc` as one of its dependencies.

After trying several steps as recommended by @[Boris](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52558100/2649145) the command below from the [Facebook Prophet project page](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/fbprophet) worked for me in the end.

```
conda install -c conda-forge fbprophet
```

It installed all the needed dependencies for `fbprophet`. Make sure you have anaconda installed.

Comment: Thank you! This gcc is causing me so many install issues that I still have not resolved and Boris steps wouldn't work for me either but that did the trick. Thank you!

Comment: yep, similarly in my case  for `marisa-trie` it worked: `conda install -c conda-forge python-marisa-trie `

Answer (score 4):

[This page](https://weasyprint.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install.html) is gonna save your life, for all further lib issues that are forthcoming,

For Alpine(>=3.6), use

```
apk --update --upgrade add gcc musl-dev jpeg-dev zlib-dev libffi-dev cairo-dev pango-dev gdk-pixbuf-dev
```

Comment: Sounds like an overkill of dependencies to me and added ~200 MB - what has ``WeasyPrint` to do with that?

But I have to state that this is the onlz thing that helped me with an Issue related to ansible in a jenkins container.

Comment: @Cadoiz enjoy :)

Answer (score 3):

**For CentOS 7.2：**

```
LSB Version:    :core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: CentOS
Description:    CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core) 
Release:    7.2.1511
Codename:   Core
```

**Install eventlet:**

```
sudo yum install python-devel
sudo easy_install -ZU eventlet
```

**Terminal info：**

```
[root@localhost ~]# easy_install -ZU eventlet
Searching for eventlet
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/eventlet/
Best match: eventlet 0.19.0
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/5a/e8/ac80f330a80c18113df0f4f872fb741974ad2179f8c2a5e3e45f40214cef/eventlet-0.19.0.tar.gz#md5=fde857181347d5b7b921541367a99204
Processing eventlet-0.19.0.tar.gz
Running eventlet-0.19.0/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-Hh9GQY/eventlet-0.19.0/egg-dist-tmp-rBFoAx
Adding eventlet 0.19.0 to easy-install.pth file

Installed /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/eventlet-0.19.0-py2.6.egg
Processing dependencies for eventlet
Finished processing dependencies for eventlet
```

Comment: When I run, it gives me the error 

"unable to execute 'gcc': No such file or directory"

Comment: @Sarang that means you haven't install gcc yet, execute:"yum -y install gcc"

Answer (score 3):

**For openSUSE 42.1 Leap Linux use this**

```
sudo zypper install python3-devel
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Note that this is as much of a comment as an answer.  There are a number of comments under the main answers which describe alternatives for different Linux distros.  I realize you can't make comments yet.  Be cautious about adding 'answers' to well-established questions which are really 'comments'.

Answer (score 2):

I am using **MacOS catalina 10.15.4**. None of the posted solutions worked for me. What worked for me is:

```
 >> xcode-select --install
xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates

>> env LDFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib" pip install psycopg2==2.8.4
Collecting psycopg2==2.8.4
  Using cached psycopg2-2.8.4.tar.gz (377 kB)
Installing collected packages: psycopg2
  Attempting uninstall: psycopg2
    Found existing installation: psycopg2 2.7.7
    Uninstalling psycopg2-2.7.7:
      Successfully uninstalled psycopg2-2.7.7
    Running setup.py install for psycopg2 ... done
Successfully installed psycopg2-2.8.4
```

use **pip3** for **python3**

Answer (score 1):

if you are on Mac as myself, try this in your terminal: `xcode-select --install`

Then accept the installation request, and it works afterwards as described [in this issue](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/3438)

Answer (score 0):

Build from source and install, this is fixed in the latest release (10.3+):

```
mkdir -p /tmp/install/netifaces/
cd /tmp/install/netifaces && wget -O "netifaces-0.10.4.tar.gz" "https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/n/netifaces/netifaces-0.10.4.tar.gz#md5=36da76e2cfadd24cc7510c2c0012eb1e"
tar xvzf netifaces-0.10.4.tar.gz
cd netifaces-0.10.4 && python setup.py install
```

Answer (score 0):

Similarly I fixed it like this (notice `python34`):

```
sudo yum install python34-devel
```

Answer (score 0):

`sudo apt install gcc`

It works for PyCharm on Ubuntu 20.10.

Answer (score 0):

If you are migrating to a more modern version of python3 e.g. `python3.5 to python3.8` You may want to check/upgrade the versions of the library that are failing if you have already installed the recommended libraries to handle gcc building `python3-dev` + other libraries as suggested.

It depends on the package. Some versions of the packages may not be supported on later versions of python3.

Answer (score 0):

On a **macOS**, if the message

```bash
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
...
```

is part of the error log, installing the developer tools could solve this issue.

The following terminal command can run the developer tools software installation:

`$ xcode-select --install`

I encountered a similar issue while installing `greenlet`, and the above resolved it.