# Compiling pyopencl

Tags: python, gcc, opencl, pyopencl

I'm trying to compile pyopencl on Ubuntu 12.10 in a virtualenv directory but it seems to be outputting an error:

```
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -Wall -O3 -DNDEBUG -fPIC -DPYGPU_PACKAGE=pyopencl -DBOOST_PYTHON_SOURCE=1 -DPYOPENCL_USE_DEVICE_FISSION=1 -DPYGPU_PYOPENCL=1 -DBOOST_MULTI_INDEX_DISABLE_SERIALIZATION=1 -DBOOST_THREAD_BUILD_DLL=1 -Dboost=pyopenclboost -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1 -Ibpl-subset/bpl_subset -I/opencl-install-location/include -I/home/stephen/Downloads/Software/poclbm/python/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c bpl-subset/bpl_subset/libs/thread/src/pthread/once.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/bpl-subset/bpl_subset/libs/thread/src/pthread/once.o
In file included from bpl-subset/bpl_subset/boost/thread/detail/platform.hpp:17:0,
                 from bpl-subset/bpl_subset/boost/thread/once.hpp:12,
                 from bpl-subset/bpl_subset/libs/thread/src/pthread/once.cpp:7:
bpl-subset/bpl_subset/boost/config/requires_threads.hpp:29:4: error: #error "Threading support unavaliable: it has been explicitly disabled with BOOST_DISABLE_THREADS"
In file included from bpl-subset/bpl_subset/boost/thread/once.hpp:12:0,
                 from bpl-subset/bpl_subset/libs/thread/src/pthread/once.cpp:7:
bpl-subset/bpl_subset/boost/thread/detail/platform.hpp:67:9: error: #error "Sorry, no boost threads are available for this platform."
In file included from bpl-subset/bpl_subset/libs/thread/src/pthread/once.cpp:7:0:
bpl-subset/bpl_subset/boost/thread/once.hpp:18:2: error: #error "Boost threads unavailable on this platform"
In file included from bpl-subset/bpl_subset/libs/thread/src/pthread/once.cpp:7:0:
bpl-subset/bpl_subset/boost/thread/once.hpp:25:42: error: variable or field ‘call_once’ declared void
bpl-subset/bpl_subset/boost/thread/once.hpp:25:34: error: ‘func’ was not declared in this scope
bpl-subset/bpl_subset/boost/thread/once.hpp:25:42: error: ‘once_flag’ was not declared in this scope
bpl-subset/bpl_subset/boost/thread/once.hpp:25:53: error: ‘flag’ was not declared in this scope
bpl-subset/bpl_subset/libs/thread/src/pthread/once.cpp:16:9: error: ‘BOOST_THREAD_DECL’ does not name a type
bpl-subset/bpl_subset/libs/thread/src/pthread/once.cpp:17:9: error: ‘BOOST_THREAD_DECL’ does not name a type
bpl-subset/bpl_subset/libs/thread/src/pthread/once.cpp:18:9: error: ‘BOOST_THREAD_DECL’ does not name a type
bpl-subset/bpl_subset/libs/thread/src/pthread/once.cpp:39:9: error: ‘uintmax_t’ in namespace ‘pyopenclboost’ does not name a type
bpl-subset/bpl_subset/libs/thread/src/pthread/once.cpp:23:28: warning: ‘pyopenclboost::detail::{anonymous}::epoch_tss_key_flag’ defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
bpl-subset/bpl_subset/libs/thread/src/pthread/once.cpp:32:29: warning: ‘void pyopenclboost::detail::{anonymous}::create_epoch_tss_key()’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
make: *** [install] Error 1
```

Comment: Possibly helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11094718/error-command-gcc-failed-with-exit-status-1-while-installing-eventlet

Comment: Didn't help... I already had it installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the git version. This came up recently on the mailing list. I'll put out an update soon.

Answer (score 0):

searching online you'll find nothing in the past year but people asking howto install this on ubuntu. I'm not sure if this helps you but if you're just trying to install it to ubuntu just use,

```
sudo apt-get install python-pyopencl
```

that should get you rolling.