# Cygwin "error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1"

Tags: python, gcc, cygwin

I was trying to download matplotlib which is required for a python program I'm trying to install and I keep getting:

"error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1"

I've seen several results for how to fix the problem on linux but haven't had much luck in finding a solution for me running python through cygwin. Could someone lead me in a direction to help solve this problem? I saw some results involving sudo apt-get but that was leading me down another path of trouble to work. 
Thanks.

Comment: Do you have gcc installed? You could try running it in a cygwin shell. If not I would suggest googling for: How to install gcc under cygwin

Comment: Were there any other errors?

Comment: Most of the results for linux are going to apply just as well for cygwin. (Of course information specific to a certain _distro_, e.g., telling you to use `apt-get` or `yum` or something, will have to be translated, but that's no different from linux either.)

Comment: There is one possible problem that's specific to cygwin, however… You are using a cygwin version of Python, not a native Windows version, right?

Comment: yes that is correct. And after checking the cygwin installer again I have everything installed for gcc.

Comment: The other errors were:
In file included from lib/matplotlib/tri/_tri.cpp:8:0:
error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant

 error: expected identifier before numeric constant

error: expected ‘{’ before numeric constant

error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant

Comment: possible duplicate of [error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1 while installing eventlet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11094718/error-command-gcc-failed-with-exit-status-1-while-installing-eventlet)

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem, The answer was here https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/2463

"There is a variable called "_C" defined in lib/matplotlib/tri/_tri.h on line 821 and invoked in tri.cpp on lines 2180 and 2186. For some reason gcc doesn't like this (is it a reserved word in some architecture?). I just renamed the variable to "_Co" in both tri.h and tri.cpp, and the compilation finished successfully."