# Installing qPython in Win7

Tags: python, kdb, q-lang

Being a newbie with Python and KDB+/Q, I tried to install [qPython](https://github.com/exxeleron/qPython) package (Python API for KDB+, not to be mistaken for QPython).

1. I downloaded and unzipped the source from 
   https://github.com/exxeleron/qPython/releases/tag/qPython-1.0-RC1
2. In Win `cmd`, I ran `python setup.py install` (from the path given by step 1 above)
3. Received the below log with errors.

What is it actually saying and how should I proceed?

---

```
Compiling qpython/fastutils.pyx because it changed.
Cythonizing qpython/fastutils.pyx
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\qpython
copying qpython\qcollection.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\qpython
copying qpython\qconnection.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\qpython
copying qpython\qreader.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\qpython
copying qpython\qtemporal.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\qpython
copying qpython\qtype.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\qpython
copying qpython\qwriter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\qpython
copying qpython\utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\qpython
copying qpython\_pandas.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\qpython
copying qpython\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\qpython
creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\samples
copying samples\async_query.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\samples
copying samples\console.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\samples
copying samples\publisher.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\samples
copying samples\sync_query.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\samples
copying samples\tick_subscriber.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\samples
copying samples\twistedclient.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\samples
copying samples\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\samples
copying LICENSE -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
copying CHANGELOG.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
copying README.rst -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
copying requirements.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
running build_ext
building 'qpython.fastutils' extension
creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7
creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release
creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\qpython
G:\R\Rtools\gcc-4.6.3\bin\gcc.exe -DMS_WIN64 -mdll -O -Wall -IG:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IG:\Anaconda\include -IG:\Anaconda\PC -c qpython/fastutils.c -o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\qpython\fastutils.o
In file included from G:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1804:0, from G:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:17, from G:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/arrayobject.h:4, from qpython/fastutils.c:232: G:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:
12:9: note: #pragma message: G:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h(12) : Warning Msg: Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by #defining NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION
qpython/fastutils.c: In function '__Pyx_RaiseArgtupleInvalid':
qpython/fastutils.c:4376:18: warning: unknown conversion type character 'z' in format [-Wformat]
qpython/fastutils.c:4376:18: warning: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char*', but argument 5 has type 'Py_ssize_t' [-Wformat]
qpython/fastutils.c:4376:18: warning: unknown conversion type character 'z' in format [-Wformat]
qpython/fastutils.c:4376:18: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
qpython/fastutils.c: In function '__Pyx_BufFmt_ProcessTypeChunk':
qpython/fastutils.c:4754:26: warning: unknown conversion type character 'z' in format [-Wformat]
qpython/fastutils.c:4754:26: warning: unknown conversion type character 'z' in format [-Wformat]
qpython/fastutils.c:4754:26: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
qpython/fastutils.c:4806:20: warning: unknown conversion type character 'z' in format [-Wformat]
qpython/fastutils.c:4806:20: warning: unknown conversion type character 'z' in format [-Wformat]
qpython/fastutils.c:4806:20: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
qpython/fastutils.c: In function '__pyx_buffmt_parse_array':
qpython/fastutils.c:4868:25: warning: unknown conversion type character 'z' in format [-Wformat]
qpython/fastutils.c:4868:25: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
qpython/fastutils.c: In function '__Pyx_GetBufferAndValidate':
qpython/fastutils.c:5053:7: warning: unknown conversion type character 'z' in format [-Wformat]
qpython/fastutils.c:5053:7: warning: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char*', but argument 3 has type 'Py_ssize_t' [-Wformat]
qpython/fastutils.c:5053:7: warning: unknown conversion type character 'z' in format [-Wformat]
qpython/fastutils.c:5053:7: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
qpython/fastutils.c: In function '__Pyx_RaiseTooManyValuesError':
qpython/fastutils.c:5413:18: warning: unknown conversion type character 'z' in format [-Wformat]
qpython/fastutils.c:5413:18: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
qpython/fastutils.c: In function '__Pyx_RaiseNeedMoreValuesError':
qpython/fastutils.c:5419:18: warning: unknown conversion type character 'z' in format [-Wformat]
qpython/fastutils.c:5419:18: warning: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char*', but argument 3 has type 'Py_ssize_t' [-Wformat]
qpython/fastutils.c:5419:18: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
qpython/fastutils.c: At top level: G:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/__multiarray_api.h:1629:1: warning: '_import_array' defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
G:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/__ufunc_api.h:241:1: warning: '_import_umath' defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
writing build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\qpython\fastutils.def
G:\R\Rtools\gcc-4.6.3\bin\gcc.exe -DMS_WIN64 -shared -s build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\qpython\fastutils.o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\qpython\fastutils.def -LG:\Anaconda\libs -LG:\Anaconda\PCbuild\amd64 -lpython27 -lmsvcr90 -o build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\qpython\fastutils.pyd
g:/r/rtools/gcc-4.6.3/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.6.3/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible G:\Anaconda\libs/libpython27.a when searching for -lpython27
g:/r/rtools/gcc-4.6.3/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.6.3/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible G:\Anaconda\libs/python27.lib when searching for -lpython27
g:/r/rtools/gcc-4.6.3/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.6.3/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible G:\Anaconda\libs\libpython27.a when searching for -lpython27
g:/r/rtools/gcc-4.6.3/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.6.3/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible G:\Anaconda\libs/libpython27.a when searching for -lpython27
g:/r/rtools/gcc-4.6.3/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.6.3/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible G:\Anaconda\libs/python27.lib when searching for -lpython27
g:/r/rtools/gcc-4.6.3/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.6.3/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible G:\Anaconda\libs\python27.lib when searching for -lpython27
g:/r/rtools/gcc-4.6.3/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.6.3/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lpython27
g:/r/rtools/gcc-4.6.3/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.6.3/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible G:\Anaconda\libs/libmsvcr90.a when searching for -lmsvcr90
g:/r/rtools/gcc-4.6.3/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.6.3/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible G:\Anaconda\libs\libmsvcr90.a when searching for -lmsvcr90
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'G:\\R\\Rtools\\gcc-4.6.3\\bin\\gcc.exe' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: why the downvote, care to give a reason? If it is because of large error log, care to advise how to make it more compact/readable (I made effort and researched ways).

Comment: I am not the downvoter, but I can guess that it's because this type of question is not a good format for the site. It's better directed at the author of the module or that specific community.

Comment: is python 2.7 installed on the system?

Comment: @user2393012 I think so. Anaconda distribution

Comment: The last line: `\\gcc.exe' failed with exit status 1`. Do I need `python-dev` installed as well? (as per this [SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11094718/error-command-gcc-failed-with-exit-status-1-while-installing-eventlet))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this is the culprit:

```
g:/r/rtools/gcc-4.6.3/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.6.3/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lpython27
```

And yes I would say you need to install python-dev to get the python27 libraries for linking to.

Comment: I had [RTools](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/) installed on my computer. After I uninstalled it, the issue disappeared. RTools seemed to have incomplatible `gcc` included in it and it masked other `gcc` installs (e.g. as part of Visual Studio 2008)

Answer (score 2):

**I have installed qpython on windows vista as given below:**

Downloaded the zip file from: https://github.com/exxeleron/qPython/archive/qPython-1.0-RC2.zip

unzipped and executed the following in the command prompt:

```
python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
```

At this stage, it gave error "error: Microsoft Visual C++ 9.0 is required (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat). Get it from http://aka.ms/vcpython27"

So, downloaded the required file http://aka.ms/vcpython27 and installed it.

Again executed:  python -m pip install -r requirements.txt

It took around 30 minutes and installed all the required modules for qpython.

Tried to install qpython by:

```
python setup.py install
```

Got the error: "error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat".

Installed Visual Studio 2010 express from: http://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs#d-2010-express

It took another 30 minutes to install.

Created new System environment variable with name 'VS90COMNTOOLS' and value 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\Tools\'

Finally, installed qpython successfully by running the command (in a new dos window):

```
python setup.py install
```