# Does anyone know how to compile Megahal on Ubuntu?

Tags: python, ubuntu

I have been trying to compile megahal for a few hours now and i dont seem to be getting anywhere. Has anyone had success with this?
http://megahal.alioth.debian.org/

I keep getting an error that says :

```
inlined from ‘load_personality.constprop’ at megahal.c:3283:8,
inlined from ‘change_personality.constprop’ at megahal.c:3332:5:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/stdio2.h:293:2: warning: call to      ‘__fread_chk_warn’ declared with attribute warning: fread called with bigger size * nmemb than length of destination buffer
return __fread_chk_warn (__ptr, __bos0 (__ptr), __size, __n, __stream);
 ^
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
Makefile:44: recipe for target 'pythonmodule' failed
make: *** [pythonmodule] Error 1
```

I have installed python via sudo apt-get and i have been over every thread that talks about "'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' but I have found no solution

Answer (score 0):

You are getting these errors just because you don't have the python development headers installed. You can install it using following command

sudo apt-get install python-dev ( for python 2.x )

sudo apt-get install python3-dev ( for python 3 )

Comment: thanks for the reply. I tried this, with both python 2 and python 3. I even removed them and tried again, the error remained.

Answer (score -1):

you need the python developer module "python-dev".this will help you

[error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1 while installing eventlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11094718/error-command-gcc-failed-with-exit-status-1-while-installing-eventlet)

after upgrading to vivid 15.04 on ubuntu i couldn't compile the module anymore so i tried something else. Since in the main folder there is a directory named Megahal with a Makefile in it, i tried to compile from there. First you need to go to that directory.

```
cd /home/user/Downloads/megahal-9.1.1/Megahal/
```

you need to go where you unzipped the archive and there you can read the README file and start compiling.

```
perl Makefile.PL
```

i copied the missing files i was able to find to that folder and from there

```
make
make test
```

but this didn't work for me and afther that

```
make install
```

i had to do

```
sudo make install
```

and that is all. unfortunately for me i have a problem with perl i think.
I keep getting this error from the module "PL_thr_key" after i load it to the eggdrop. The eggdrop works normally except for the module. No module, no AI and no fun :(

Comment: thanks for the reply. Its weird, this kind of worked. make test is the only step that didnt work, but when i try launch megahal from command prompt theres still nothing. The gcc error still occurs when i try compile from cd /home/user/Downloads/megahal-9.1.1