# odoo install failed on CentOS 6.7 (command "pip install pyopenssl")

Tags: python, linux, pip, odoo, cartography

Good afternoon,

Im trying to install odoo CRM into a CentOS 6.7 minimal VM (RamNode). The guide I'm following is:

https://odootricks.wordpress.com/2014/09/30/installing-odoo-8-on-centos-6-with-virtual-python-install/

So python 2.7 will be installed with altinstall option and everything will be on virtualenv.

Everything works ok till the install of pyopenssl. The "pip install pyopenssl" command fails and I haven`t been able to make it work...

Already tried to manually install cryptography, updated setuptools, updated pip, etc and nothing seem to work...

Posible solutions that I already tried:

```
pip install -U pip
pip install -U setuptools
yum install pyOpenSSL
yum install gcc libffi-devel python-devel openssl-devel
pip install --upgrade Distribute
yum -y install python-pip
```

Im really out of options to try here, any help would be very appreciated.

```
    (odoo)[odoo@casilleros ~]$ pip install cryptography
Collecting cryptography
/home/odoo/odoo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
  Using cached cryptography-1.0.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): idna>=2.0 in ./odoo/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from cryptography)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pyasn1>=0.1.8 in ./odoo/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from cryptography)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six>=1.4.1 in ./odoo/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from cryptography)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): setuptools in ./odoo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-18.2-py2.7.egg (from cryptography)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): enum34 in ./odoo/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from cryptography)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): ipaddress in ./odoo/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from cryptography)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): cffi>=1.1.0 in ./odoo/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from cryptography)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pycparser in ./odoo/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from cffi>=1.1.0->cryptography)
Building wheels for collected packages: cryptography
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for cryptography
  Complete output from command /home/odoo/odoo/bin/python2.7 -c "import setuptools;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-Xoq8de/cryptography/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmpEfTxmepip-wheel-:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography
  copying src/cryptography/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography
  copying src/cryptography/__about__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography
  copying src/cryptography/exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography
  copying src/cryptography/utils.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography
  copying src/cryptography/fernet.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/x509
  copying src/cryptography/x509/general_name.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/x509
  copying src/cryptography/x509/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/x509
  copying src/cryptography/x509/base.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/x509
  copying src/cryptography/x509/name.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/x509
  copying src/cryptography/x509/oid.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/x509
  copying src/cryptography/x509/extensions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/x509
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/hmac.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/constant_time.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/cmac.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/serialization.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/padding.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/hashes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/interfaces.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/multibackend.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/bindings
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/bindings
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/interfaces
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/interfaces/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/interfaces
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor/utils.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor/totp.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor/hotp.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf/pbkdf2.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf/concatkdf.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf/hkdf.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers/modes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers/base.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers/algorithms.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/dsa.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/dh.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/rsa.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/padding.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/utils.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/ec.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/commoncrypto
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/commoncrypto/hmac.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/commoncrypto
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/commoncrypto/backend.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/commoncrypto
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/commoncrypto/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/commoncrypto
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/commoncrypto/ciphers.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/commoncrypto
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/commoncrypto/hashes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/commoncrypto
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/dsa.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/hmac.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/backend.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/rsa.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/cmac.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/x509.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/utils.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/ciphers.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/ec.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/hashes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/commoncrypto
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/commoncrypto/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/commoncrypto
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/commoncrypto/binding.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/commoncrypto
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/binding.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/_conditional.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl
  running egg_info
  writing requirements to src/cryptography.egg-info/requires.txt
  writing src/cryptography.egg-info/PKG-INFO
  writing top-level names to src/cryptography.egg-info/top_level.txt
  writing dependency_links to src/cryptography.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
  writing entry points to src/cryptography.egg-info/entry_points.txt
  warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

  reading manifest file 'src/cryptography.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
  no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'vectors'
  writing manifest file 'src/cryptography.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  running build_ext
  generating cffi module 'build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_padding.c'
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
  generating cffi module 'build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_constant_time.c'
  generating cffi module 'build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c'
  building '_openssl' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/build
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
  gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/local/include/python2.7 -c build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.o
  build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c:1735: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype
  gcc: Internal error: Killed (program cc1)
  Please submit a full bug report.
  See <http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla> for instructions.
  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for cryptography
Failed to build cryptography
Installing collected packages: cryptography
  Running setup.py install for cryptography
    Complete output from command /home/odoo/odoo/bin/python2.7 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-Xoq8de/cryptography/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-d1Fqxd-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/odoo/odoo/include/site/python2.7/cryptography:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    running egg_info
    writing requirements to src/cryptography.egg-info/requires.txt
    writing src/cryptography.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing top-level names to src/cryptography.egg-info/top_level.txt
    writing dependency_links to src/cryptography.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing entry points to src/cryptography.egg-info/entry_points.txt
    warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

    reading manifest file 'src/cryptography.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'vectors'
    writing manifest file 'src/cryptography.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    running build_ext
    generating cffi module 'build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_padding.c'
    already up-to-date
    generating cffi module 'build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_constant_time.c'
    already up-to-date
    generating cffi module 'build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c'
    building '_openssl' extension
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/local/include/python2.7 -c build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.o
    build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c:1735: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype
    gcc: Internal error: Killed (program cc1)
    Please submit a full bug report.
    See <http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla> for instructions.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/home/odoo/odoo/bin/python2.7 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-Xoq8de/cryptography/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-d1Fqxd-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/odoo/odoo/include/site/python2.7/cryptography" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-Xoq8de/cryptography
```

Comment: Did you by any chance move the virtualenv directory?
Also check the answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11094718/error-command-gcc-failed-with-exit-status-1-while-installing-eventlet you may need to sudo the python-devel package.

Comment: already installed python-devel as root and I don't think I moved the virtualenv directory... the thing is I already made it in a virtual environment (VirtualBox testing machine) but in my production server can't make it

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might need to use your package manager, `sudo apt-get install` or equivelent to install both openssl and openssl-dev (probably as super user).

Comment: `yum install openssl openssl-devel
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.mia.host-engine.com
 * epel: reflector.westga.edu
 * extras: reflector.westga.edu
 * updates: cosmos.cites.illinois.edu
Package openssl-1.0.1e-42.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package openssl-devel-1.0.1e-42.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do`