# error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1 --> in python3.7.1 and ubuntu 19.04

Tags: c++, c, django, python-3.x, gcc

I switch of ubuntu 16 to ubuntu 19 and dose not work gcc 
this error is:
 error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1 --> in python3.7.1 and ubuntu 19.04

```
sudo apt-get install python3.7-dev
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

i test this link but does not work:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35048582/how-to-fix-error-command-x86-64-linux-gnu-gcc-failed-with-exit-status-1
```

---

```
       Compile failed: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
  creating tmp
  cc -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/libxml2 -c /tmp/xmlXPathInitfuvqfw8a.c -o tmp/xmlXPathInitfuvqfw8a.o
  /tmp/xmlXPathInitfuvqfw8a.c:2:1: warning: return type defaults to ‘int’ [-Wimplicit-int]
   main (int argc, char **argv) {
   ^~~~
  cc tmp/xmlXPathInitfuvqfw8a.o -lxml2 -o a.out
  error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for lxml
  Running setup.py clean for lxml
  Building wheel for numpy (setup.py) ...
```

I'm very try but i can not solve problem 
help me thanks

Comment: You probably should be asking about this on the mailing list for the software you're trying to install.

Comment: Seems your `main` function is not complete, and the compiler is taking warnings as errors.

Comment: I after activate virtualenv  and enter `pip3 install -r requirements.txt` then i got into error i now switch to ubuntu 18 LTS and solve problem.