# error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1 while installing PyObjC (Python 2.7)

Tags: python-2.7

I'm relatively new to Python (and programming in general) so go easy on me. I've been aiming to install the pyautogui module which is dependant on having PyObjC installed:

```
pip install -U pyobjc-core                              
pip install -U pyobjc
```

I successfully installed 'pyobjc-core'. I have also successfully installed 'xcode-select --install'. When I try to install 'pyobjc' I get the error:

```
3 errors generated.  
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I am using Python 2.7. Please ask for any more information that could help. Help me out, thanks in advance.

Comment: try to install the  python development headers -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11094718/error-command-gcc-failed-with-exit-status-1-while-installing-eventlet

Answer (score 0):

Hum... perhaps your answer can be here [error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1 while installing eventlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11094718/error-command-gcc-failed-with-exit-status-1-while-installing-eventlet)

> Your install is failing because you don't have the python development headers installed. You can do this through apt on ubuntu/debian with:
>
> `sudo apt-get install python-dev`

Best of luck and welcome to programming

Comment: So I tried: `sudo apt-get install python-dev` It returned: `sudo: apt-get: command not found` I then tried `sudo apt-get install software-properties-common python-software-properties` to try to install the software-properties-common package. This is part of Ubuntu, which I also was not aware about. I failed to mention earlier that I am using Mac OS 10.11.4. I was unable to download Ubuntu on my Mac, reason being there is 'no mountable file system'. Is Ubuntu only for Linux? I feel like I'm working at this backwards. Any clues or direction would be MUCH appreciated. Thanks.