# python install all in requirements.txt

Tags: python, linux

im have requirements.txt 
in /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/requirements.txt 
 with next

```
Flask==0.10.1
gunicorn
requests
google-api-python-client
gcloud
numpy
lxml
oauth2client==2.0.1
pandas==0.18.0
```

And im wnat install all dependency lib
im run comand

```
sudo apt-get install libevent-dev
sudo apt-get install python3-dev
pip install -r /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/requirements.txt
```

its begining installatian and next return error

> error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
>
> ---------------------------------------- Cleaning up... Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools,
>   tokenize;**file**='/tmp/pip-build-VE4Yke/lxml/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), **file**,
>   'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-BxiyFk-record/install-record.txt
>   --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-VE4Yke/lxml Storing debug log for failure in
>   /root/.pip/pip.log

Comment: Did you see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11094718/error-command-gcc-failed-with-exit-status-1-while-installing-eventlet) yet? It is very similar. You are probably missing `python-dev`?

Comment: run sudo apt-get install python3-dev
and run  pip install -r /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/requirements.txt 
But its not helped

Comment: I just noticed the error is around lxml. Did you try `apt-get install python-lxml`? If you are using Python3: `apt-get install python3-lxml`.

Comment: return next:
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3-bs4
 python3-lxml
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: Check this out: http://askubuntu.com/questions/688338/e-sub-process-usr-bin-dpkg-returned-an-error-code-1-related-to-google-chrom . There just seems to be a combination of missing dependencies and odd issues going on in your linux env. I would keep looking up the errors you get and see what solutions are proposed and try those out.

Comment: yes, im have, file is create

Comment: Check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26053982/error-setup-script-exited-with-error-command-x86-64-linux-gnu-gcc-failed-wit