# How to install python3-devel on red hat 7

Tags: python-3.x, installation, virtualenv, rhel7

I am trying to install something in my virtual environment, which uses anaconda python 3.6. I get `the gcc failed with exit status 1`, hinting on the absence of the right python3-devel package, as described in [error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1 while installing eventlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11094718/error-command-gcc-failed-with-exit-status-1-while-installing-eventlet).

To fix the error, I tried to install the python3-devel package on my server running RHEL 7.3. 
I did `yum install python3-devel`, but got a `'package not found'` error. Then I found https://serverfault.com/questions/710354/repository-for-python3-devel-on-centos-7, which hints to the python34-devel package in the EPEL repository. I installed it using yum, but upon trying to install something in my virtual environment, I still get `the gcc failed with exit status 1` error.

Does someone know how I can fix this? All help would be much apprechiated.

Comment: "gcc failed with exit status 1" is the symptom, not the cause.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. As I describe in my post, I believe the cause to be the absence of the python3-devel package.

Comment: Okay, but nothing in the question backs that up.

Comment: True, added my source.

Comment: As a sidenote, I would recommend Red Hat Software Collections for installing Python3 instead of EPEL -- you get official support with that. See https://access.redhat.com/solutions/472793

Answer (score 125, accepted):

Search for the package in yum , use the following command:

```
yum search python3 | grep devel
```

It will list all the available devel packages. The result will be somewhat like this

> ```
> python3-cairo-devel.x86_64 : Libraries and headers for python3-cairo
> python3-devel.x86_64 : Libraries and header files needed for Python 3
>                      : development
> python34-devel.x86_64 : Libraries and header files needed for Python 3
>                       : development
> ```

Then you can choose the package you want to install from the list , suppose if you want to to install python3-devel , execute the following

```
yum install -y python3-devel.x86_64
```

Comment: `# yum search python3 //
Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager //
Warning: No matches found for: python3
No matches found`  -- couldn't find it on my system

Comment: I want to give you 2 points but SO won't let me ... thanks man ... this is BY FAR the most straight forward answer

Comment: The above did not work for me, probably because I did not have repositories setup, so I found this here which worked:https://draculaservers.com/tutorials/install-python-3-centos-7/
Or just this----------------------------------------
sudo yum install centos-release-scl
sudo yum install rh-python36
scl enable rh-python36 bash
python --version

Comment: Which repo is python3-devel found?  I have base, extras, epel and ius configured and it is not found.  Pip search can't find it.  I can only seem to find it on rpmfind.net and that is a source rpm.

Answer (score 14):

I thought I might update this for 2020.  As of RHEL 7.7, python-devel is not available in EPEL, it has been retired by Fedora Project.  All I wanted for today was the python h files, and this got me there:

```
# yum install python3-devel.x86_64 --enablerepo=rhel-7-server-optional-rpms
```

We do have one of the Redhat No-Cost Developer licenses, but I am not sure that is required for the optional-rpms.

PS, this was helpful in verifying which packages of interest were in optional-rpms

```
# yum repo-pkgs rhel-7-server-optional-rpms list | grep python3
```

Answer (score 13):

There are no `python3-*` packages from Red Hat in Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 or 7.

However there are `python3-*` packages available if you enable **third party repos** like EPEL or IUS.  But, these are not supported by Red Hat.  Chances are if you are running RHEL, your organization has a preference for supported packages.

You can get supported Python 3 packages from Red Hat via Red Hat Software Collections (RHSCL). Currently Python 3.6 is the newest available, the package name is rh-python36.  Installing the RHSCL package will also install rh-python36-devel and a number of other packages.

See [How to install Python 3, pip, venv, virtualenv, and pipenv on RHEL](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2018/08/13/install-python3-rhel/)

Don't forget to install @development first, so you have gcc, make, etc. for building any dynamically loaded shared objects.

To install:

```
$ su -
# subscription-manager repos --enable rhel-7-server-optional-rpms \
  --enable rhel-server-rhscl-7-rpms
# yum -y install @development
# yum -y install rh-python36

# yum -y install rh-python36-numpy \
 rh-python36-scipy \ 
 rh-python36-python-tools \
 rh-python36-python-six

# exit
```

The blog linked above has lots of tips for working with Python, virtual environments, as well as software collections on Red Hat.