# Installing python36-devel on rhel7 failing

Tags: python-3.6, yum, rhel7

Trying to install python36-devel on RHEL7, ends up getting error

Tried resolving the dependencies as stated in error, but no help.

Also tried this [How to install python3-devel on red hat 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43047284/how-to-install-python3-devel-on-red-hat-7), which also ended up in same error

`yum install python36-devel`

Error:

```
Loaded plugins: amazon-id, rhui-lb, search-disabled-repos
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package python36-devel.x86_64 0:3.6.8-1.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: python36 = 3.6.8-1.el7 for package: python36-devel-3.6.8-1.el7.x86_64
Package python36-3.6.8-1.el7.x86_64 is obsoleted by python3-3.6.8-10.el7.x86_64 which is already installed
--> Processing Dependency: python36-libs(x86-64) = 3.6.8-1.el7 for package: python36-devel-3.6.8-1.el7.x86_64
Package python36-libs-3.6.8-1.el7.x86_64 is obsoleted by python3-libs-3.6.8-10.el7.x86_64 which is already installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: python36-devel-3.6.8-1.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: python36-libs(x86-64) = 3.6.8-1.el7
           Installed: python3-libs-3.6.8-10.el7.x86_64 (@rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases)
               python36-libs(x86-64) = 3.6.8-10.el7
           Available: python36-libs-3.6.8-1.el7.x86_64 (epel)
               python36-libs(x86-64) = 3.6.8-1.el7
Error: Package: python36-devel-3.6.8-1.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: python36 = 3.6.8-1.el7
           Installed: python3-3.6.8-10.el7.x86_64 (@rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases)
               python36 = 3.6.8-10.el7
           Available: python36-3.6.8-1.el7.x86_64 (epel)
               python36 = 3.6.8-1.el7
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Comment: I'm running into the same.

Comment: a quick glance looks like its a package conflict between `@rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases` and `epel` repos. try disabling the `@rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases` one and see if that fixes it.

Comment: @user3788685 When it says, `python3-3.6.8-10.el7.x86_64 which is already installed`, does it mean we already have development tools in the system?

Comment: yes - do `rpm -q python3` and it should return the same thing - that means you have that version installed. but thats just the base version of python - not the devel headers.

Comment: I get offered `python36` and `python36-devel` when I ask yum both from the epel repo. alas I can't install on the machine im checking.

Comment: @user3788685 disabling helped

Comment: @Aks no problem - do you want me to write you up an answer?

Comment: `yum install python36-devel` fails on a fresh oracle-linux VM with no existing python installed on the system. Seems to me the yum config got screwed up in the last week with different packages requiring either python3-libs or python36-libs

Answer (score 3):

`yum` doesn't like downgrading packages unless you explicitly tell him to.

`python36-devel` requires `python36-libs` with the exact same version number. You have however `python36-libs` installed with a **higher** version number. You have two options:

1. find out why `yum` can only find an older version of `python36-devel`, logically you should be able to find `python36-devel-3.6.8-10` in the same repository where you installed `python36-libs` from (@rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases).
2. downgrade `python36-libs` to the same version as the `python36-devel` you are trying to install.

To downgrade and install `python36-devel`:

```
yum downgrade python36-libs-3.6.8-1.el7.x86_64
yum install python36-devel
```

or even in one single operation might work:

```
yum swap -- downgrade python36-libs-3.6.8-1.el7.x86_64 -- install python36-devel
```

Answer (score 2):

As of Aug 23rd, 2019, I found the following workaround to deal with python36-3.6.8-1 in ol7_developer_EPEL repo lagging behind python36-3.6.8-10 in ol7_latest.

```
yum install -y gcc openssl redhat-rpm-config
&& yum-config-manager --disable ol7_latest
&& yum install -y python36 python36-devel python36-setuptools
&& pip3 install -r requirements.txt
&& python3 setup.py install
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the repo **@rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases** have python3-libs-3.6.8-10.el7.x86_64 but not the lower version of **python36-libs-3.6.8-1.el7.x86_64**.

As pointed by [Chris Maes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2082964/chris-maes), python36-devel and python36-libs should be of the exact same version.

**epel** repo had both the libraries of the same version, but due to conflict with **@rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases** the installation was getting upgraded.

Hence, disable the repo **@rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases** and use **epel** for both of the libraries

```
sudo yum-config-manager --disable rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases
sudo yum-config-manager --disable @rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases
sudo yum install python36-setuptools -y 
sudo yum install python36-devel -y 
# enable later
sudo yum-config-manager --enable rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases
sudo yum-config-manager --enable @rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases
```

Solution credit: [user3788685](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3788685/user3788685)