# How to modify gcc command inside pip

Tags: python, gcc, pip

During installation python-ldap using pip (pip install python-ldap) I receive error:

```
Modules/common.h:9:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
 #include "Python.h"
                    ^
compilation terminated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I'm doing this inside my virtual environment (python -m venv)

I was trying to find answer for my question here:

- [Python.h: No such file or directory when installing pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48036456/python-h-no-such-file-or-directory-when-installing-pandas)
- [How to install python3-devel on red hat 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43047284/how-to-install-python3-devel-on-red-hat-7)
- [fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21530577/fatal-error-python-h-no-such-file-or-directory)

Steps which were made in order to try to fix the error but didn't:

```
yum install rh-python36-python-devel.x86_64
```

I have also checked if Python.h file is inside one of the gcc command from pip arguments:

```
    gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -I/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/include -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -DHAVE_SASL -DHAVE_TLS -DHAVE_LIBLDAP_R -DHAVE_LIBLDAP_R -DLDAPMODULE_VERSION=3.2.0 -DLDAPMODULE_AUTHOR=python-ldap project -DLDAPMODULE_LICENSE=Python style -IModules -I/me01/apps/onetick/apps/temp/venv2/include -I/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/include/python3.6m -c Modules/LDAPObject.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/Modules/LDAPObject.o
```

And the Python.h is not located inside all above locations, it is inside /opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/include/python3.6m/Python.h. Question is:

How to modify gcc command which is executed by pip?

PS Also tried

```
 "pip command here" --global-option=build_ext --global-option="-l /path/to/libraries/"
```

PSS I have found workaround:

Copy libraries inside venv/include.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As nobody answered question here is the solution.
I don't know exactly when, why and under what circumstances *gcc* is executed during *pip install* command, however in our linux system there is CC variable which in my configuration is set to "gcc" probably because by *yum install devtoolset-8*.
When I set CC command to below one, gcc knew where also to look for libraries:

```
export CC="gcc -I/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/include/python3.6m/"
```

after this *pip install python-ldap* worked well.

Knowledge:

https://developers.redhat.com/HW/gcc-RHEL-7/

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Option-Summary.html#Option-Summary