# error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1 while installing pycrypto on RHEL

Tags: python, gcc, rhel, pycrypto, rhel7

I am trying to manually install Crypto module for Python (pycrypto) on RHEL. However, I seem to always get this error after I run the build command (i.e. python setup.py build):

> error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any missing libraries or dependencies? `pycrypto` installation mentions:

> The modules are packaged using the Distutils

Also, this might be a possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11094752/5224887

Comment: Yes I believed it has some missing libraries. I have installed all the gcc packages using `yum install *gcc`, and I think I still need to install the `python-devel` but somehow it always fails to be installed. This is the error: `Error: Package: python-devel-2.6.6-64.el6.x86_64 (rhel-6-server-rpms)
           Requires: python-libs(x86-64) = 2.6.6-64.el6
           Installed: python-libs-2.6.6-66.el6_8.x86_64 (@rhel6-patch-channel-may2015)
               python-libs(x86-64) = 2.6.6-66.el6_8`

Comment: Looks like the yum package is an older release and looking for an older relear of python-libs as well. I'm not able to find a `python-devel` package for the `66.el6_8` release for RHEL (found one for CentOS). I believe finding a suitable release will solve this problem.

Comment: If you know how to handle a CentOS package on your RHEL/fedora distribution, here is the link to the appropriate `python-devel` package: https://centos.pkgs.org/6/centos-x86_64/python-devel-2.6.6-66.el6_8.x86_64.rpm.html