# Fbprophet Installation error - failed to build wheel

Tags: python, pip

I tried to install fbprophet but it fails and returns this error

```
sudo pip3.6 install fbprophet



ERROR: Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3.6 -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-9ulcpzqe/fbprophet/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-0wiofidt/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    ERROR: running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib
    creating build/lib/fbprophet
    creating build/lib/fbprophet/stan_model
    INFO:pystan:COMPILING THE C++ CODE FOR MODEL anon_model_861b75c6337e237650a61ae58c4385ef NOW.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "/usr/bin/python3.6 -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-9ulcpzqe/fbprophet/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-0wiofidt/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-9ulcpzqe/fbprophet/
```

Comment: [fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21530768)

Comment: Maybe this helps? https://stackoverflow.com/a/52558100/1577947

Comment: I tried all the solutions, but none worked