# Django Heroku - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_heroku'

Tags: django, heroku

I am deploying on heroku a website but I am experiencing some issue.
My project is called `mysite-project`.

I did the following:

1) Create a **Procfile** containing:

`web: gunicorn mysite-project.wsgi`

at the base root of my project (same level where manage.py is).

2) **app/settings.py**

`import django_heroku` at the top

`django_heroku.settings(locals())` at the bottom of settings.py

3)

```
pip install gunicorn
pip install django-heroku
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

4) If I run `python manage.py runserver` I get:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_heroku'
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There was a problem with:

```
pip install django-heroku
```

It was not fully installed because thee was a problem with `psycopg2` that was not installed.
To install `psycopg2`, run:

```
pip install psycopg2
```

Then you can run `pip install django-heroku` and the error disappeared.

You can also try installing:

`pip install psycopg2-binary`

if the error persists

Comment: I get the following error while trying to install `psycopg2` :

`error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1` 
I'm using Mac running Catalina.

Comment: @Dev_mjm Please check : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11094718/error-command-gcc-failed-with-exit-status-1-while-installing-eventlet

Comment: @Dev_mjm, I, too, cannot install `django-heroku` because I need to install `psycopg2`. Installing `psycopg2-binary` works, but not if you want to install `django-heroku`. I'm on macOS Sierra

Comment: How is this an answer? He is asking you for the solution with Heroku deployment..

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as well. I have psycopg2 installed. (for postgres)

Installing 'psycopg2- binary' solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the error was due to **adding django-heroku to installed apps** in settings.py..,**removing it** solved the issue.