# Django Application stops launching

Tags: python, django, heroku

I am trying to launch my Django app that I deployed on heroku some month ago. It has been working all these days until today after I added some pictures. When I tried to launch it, I got an Application Error message. I tried to push it again and it was successfully deployed but it is not launching. What could be the problem, please? Here are the logs.

```
2020-12-31T10:06:41.595301+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 119, in init_process
2020-12-31T10:06:41.595302+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2020-12-31T10:06:41.595302+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 144, in load_wsgi
2020-12-31T10:06:41.595303+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2020-12-31T10:06:41.595304+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2020-12-31T10:06:41.595304+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2020-12-31T10:06:41.595305+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load
2020-12-31T10:06:41.595305+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2020-12-31T10:06:41.595305+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 39, in load_wsgiapp
2020-12-31T10:06:41.595306+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2020-12-31T10:06:41.595306+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 358, in import_app
2020-12-31T10:06:41.595307+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2020-12-31T10:06:41.595307+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
2020-12-31T10:06:41.595312+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2020-12-31T10:06:41.595313+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
2020-12-31T10:06:41.595314+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
2020-12-31T10:06:41.595314+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2020-12-31T10:06:41.595314+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
2020-12-31T10:06:41.595315+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
2020-12-31T10:06:41.595315+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
2020-12-31T10:06:41.595315+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/megafishfarms/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
2020-12-31T10:06:41.595316+00:00 app[web.1]: application = get_wsgi_application()
2020-12-31T10:06:41.595316+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
2020-12-31T10:06:41.595317+00:00 app[web.1]: django.setup(set_prefix=False)
2020-12-31T10:06:41.595317+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
2020-12-31T10:06:41.595317+00:00 app[web.1]: configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
2020-12-31T10:06:41.595318+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 83, in __getattr__
2020-12-31T10:06:41.595318+00:00 app[web.1]: self._setup(name)
2020-12-31T10:06:41.595319+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 70, in _setup
2020-12-31T10:06:41.595319+00:00 app[web.1]: self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
2020-12-31T10:06:41.595319+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 177, in __init__
2020-12-31T10:06:41.595320+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
2020-12-31T10:06:41.595320+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
2020-12-31T10:06:41.595321+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2020-12-31T10:06:41.595321+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
2020-12-31T10:06:41.595321+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
2020-12-31T10:06:41.595322+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2020-12-31T10:06:41.595322+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
2020-12-31T10:06:41.595323+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
2020-12-31T10:06:41.595323+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
2020-12-31T10:06:41.595323+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/megafishfarms/settings.py", line 12, in <module>
2020-12-31T10:06:41.595324+00:00 app[web.1]: import django_heroku
2020-12-31T10:06:41.595324+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_heroku'
2020-12-31T10:06:41.595655+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-12-31 10:06:41 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2020-12-31T10:06:41.606466+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-12-31 10:06:41 +0000] [11] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2020-12-31T10:06:41.606468+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-12-31T10:06:41.606468+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
2020-12-31T10:06:41.606469+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2020-12-31T10:06:41.606469+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 119, in init_process
2020-12-31T10:06:41.606470+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2020-12-31T10:06:41.606470+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 144, in load_wsgi
2020-12-31T10:06:41.606471+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2020-12-31T10:06:41.606472+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2020-12-31T10:06:41.606472+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2020-12-31T10:06:41.606473+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load
2020-12-31T10:06:41.606473+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2020-12-31T10:06:41.606473+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 39, in load_wsgiapp
2020-12-31T10:06:41.606474+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2020-12-31T10:06:41.606474+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 358, in import_app
2020-12-31T10:06:41.606474+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2020-12-31T10:06:41.606475+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
2020-12-31T10:06:41.606475+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2020-12-31T10:06:41.606476+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
2020-12-31T10:06:41.606476+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
2020-12-31T10:06:41.606477+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2020-12-31T10:06:41.606477+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
2020-12-31T10:06:41.606478+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
2020-12-31T10:06:41.606478+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
2020-12-31T10:06:41.606478+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/megafishfarms/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
2020-12-31T10:06:41.606479+00:00 app[web.1]: application = get_wsgi_application()
2020-12-31T10:06:41.606479+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
2020-12-31T10:06:41.606480+00:00 app[web.1]: django.setup(set_prefix=False)
2020-12-31T10:06:41.606480+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
2020-12-31T10:06:41.606480+00:00 app[web.1]: configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
2020-12-31T10:06:41.606481+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 83, in __getattr__
2020-12-31T10:06:41.606481+00:00 app[web.1]: self._setup(name)
2020-12-31T10:06:41.606482+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 70, in _setup
2020-12-31T10:06:41.606482+00:00 app[web.1]: self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
2020-12-31T10:06:41.606482+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 177, in __init__
2020-12-31T10:06:41.606483+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
2020-12-31T10:06:41.606483+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
2020-12-31T10:06:41.606483+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2020-12-31T10:06:41.606484+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
2020-12-31T10:06:41.606484+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
2020-12-31T10:06:41.606485+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2020-12-31T10:06:41.606485+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
2020-12-31T10:06:41.606485+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
2020-12-31T10:06:41.606486+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
2020-12-31T10:06:41.606486+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/megafishfarms/settings.py", line 12, in <module>
2020-12-31T10:06:41.606487+00:00 app[web.1]: import django_heroku
2020-12-31T10:06:41.606495+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_heroku'
2020-12-31T10:06:41.606879+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-12-31 10:06:41 +0000] [11] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 11)
2020-12-31T10:06:41.768490+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-12-31 10:06:41 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2020-12-31T10:06:41.768597+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-12-31 10:06:41 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2020-12-31T10:06:41.852989+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2020-12-31T10:06:41.890660+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2020-12-31T10:06:55.686322+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=mbgmegafishfarms.herokuapp.com request_id=332a0fad-79a8-458d-9a42-656ef456ad90 fwd="188.162.48.253" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-12-31T10:06:55.970032+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=mbgmegafishfarms.herokuapp.com request_id=8a3377c5-0aa2-4d98-9a94-aed8d8cfe7ae fwd="188.162.48.253" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-12-31T10:06:58.532699+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=mbgmegafishfarms.herokuapp.com request_id=5b971197-7a4a-45d2-b3bd-81f48ae00a77 fwd="188.162.48.253" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-12-31T10:06:58.917286+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=mbgmegafishfarms.herokuapp.com request_id=a2d183e9-bb55-4faf-a9dc-054550f2a5c0 fwd="188.162.48.253" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: please share the requirements.py file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django Heroku - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django\_heroku'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57416061/django-heroku-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-django-heroku)

Comment: Thank you all. The problem was in my requirements file. I have solved it.