# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_heroku' when pushing to heroku

Tags: python, heroku

I am trying to upload my project to Heroku and using python 3.11.2. I migrated and was able to run server after changing settings. My Procfile contains:

```
web gunicorn albion.wsgi:application --log-file -
release: python manage.py migrate
```

When uploading, I'm getting this error from Heroku:

```
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1206, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1149, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/app/Albion/settings.py", line 15, in <module>
    import django_heroku
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_heroku'
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 440, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 415, in run_from_argv
    connections.close_all()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 84, in close_all
    for conn in self.all(initialized_only=True):
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 76, in all
    return [
           ^
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 73, in __iter__
    return iter(self.settings)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 57, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 45, in settings
    self._settings = self.configure_settings(self._settings)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 148, in configure_settings
    databases = super().configure_settings(databases)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 50, in configure_settings
    settings = getattr(django_settings, self.settings_name)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 92, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 79, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 190, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1206, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1149, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/app/Albion/settings.py", line 15, in <module>
    import django_heroku
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_heroku'
```

My settings file looks like:

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
import django_heroku


# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
# Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'xxxxxxxxxxx'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['albion.herokuapp.com', 'localhost', '10.0.2.2',]
DOMAIN_URL = 'albion.herokuapp.com' 


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'dashboard',
    'Albion',
    'bootstrap4',
    'django_heroku',

    
    ]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware'

]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'Albion.urls'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedStaticFilesStorage'
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'Albion.wsgi.application'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'Albion.wsgi.application'


DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'd8hbkrvq4d5uil',
        'USER':'vcnmsqzehqsdfd',
        'PASSWORD':'xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        'HOST':'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        'PORT':'5432'
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
django_heroku.settings(locals())

# STATICFILES_DIRS = (
#     os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
# )
DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.AutoField'
```

I have my requirements.txt setup

```
asgiref==3.6.0
certifi==2022.12.7
charset-normalizer==3.0.1
distlib==0.3.6
dj-database-url==1.2.0
Django==3.2.18
django-heroku==0.3.1
filelock==3.9.0
idna==3.4
importlib-metadata==6.0.0
platformdirs==3.0.0
psycopg2-binary==2.9.5
pytz==2022.7.1
requests==2.28.2
sqlparse==0.4.3
typing-extensions==4.5.0
urllib3==1.26.14
virtualenv==20.20.0
whitenoise==6.4.0
zipp==3.15.0
```

What do I need to do to resolve the error and get the upload the app to heroku?

Comment: `django-heroku` has been deprecated. Please see the linked duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

seems like you need to add `django-heroku` to Heroku either via console:

```
pip install django-heroku
```

or via the `requirements.txt` file:

```
django-heroku==0.3.1
```

Comment: I have it added.

Comment: did you also trigger the update: `pip freeze > requirements.txt` and then push the changes to Git so it'll redeploy the app.

Comment: Did that as well then pushed the changes.

Comment: might also help you out: [ModuleNotFoundError. "django-heroku"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57416061/django-heroku-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-django-heroku)