# fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory, python-Levenshtein install

Tags: python, python-3.x, gcc

Firstly, I'm working on an Amazon EC2 instance, Amazon linux version 2 AMI using Python 3.7.

I'm trying to install the python-Levenshtein package using the command:

```
pip3 install python-Levenshtein --user
```

and I'm getting a rather huge error, with the key parts being;

```
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c Levenshtein/_levenshtein.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/Levenshtein/_levenshtein.o
Levenshtein/_levenshtein.c:99:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
 #include <Python.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

and:

```
Command "/usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-m87wdfsg/python-Levenshtein/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-w3meudfd-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-m87wdfsg/python-Levenshtein/
```

I've tried many, many solutions, the main one being this:
[error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1 while installing eventlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11094718/error-command-gcc-failed-with-exit-status-1-while-installing-eventlet)

### Edit

Tried this...

```
1) sudo yum install python-devel (no change)
2) reinstalling GCC (no change)
3) spinning up a clean EC2 instance (same error)
4) pip install python-dev-tools (now gives me the error repeated 2x)
5) attempting to find Python.h using 'locate "Python.h"' (nothing)
6) sudo yum list python37-devel (error: no matching packages)
```

Comment: Install your operating system's `python-dev` package or equivalent. If you just say you tried "many" things, that doesn't help us rule any of them out. You'll need to be specific.

Comment: the link attached had the list of things that ive tried. ive pasted them in the message now

Comment: ...now that we know that you're using an image that uses rpm as its package manager: What does `rpm -qf /usr/bin/python3` say?

Comment: python3-3.7.4-1.amzn2.0.2.x86_64

Comment: Okay, then it'll definitely be `python3-devel` you want, not just plain `python-devel` (or `python37-devel`).

Comment: awesome, thank you. that worked. cant believe ive been googling so long for something so simple

Comment: @CharlesDuffy `$ sudo apt install python3-dev` solves this issue on Ubuntu bionic . It is like missing dependency for the build .

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Thanks to Charles, the answer is as follows:

> sudo yum install python3-devel

Comment: I hit the same problem when trying to install `psycopg2` on EC2 with Amazon linux. I am using python3.8, so installing `python3-devel` doesn't work for me. I have to do `sudo yum install python38-devel` to resolve the issue.

Comment: for similar issue in ubuntu, I used `sudo apt install python3-dev`, fixed it. Thanks.