# Getting an fatal error when installing python package on EMR notebook: Python.h: No such file or directory

Tags: python, pyspark, pip, amazon-emr

I need to install `ahocorasick` package on EMR notebook.

But when I call:

```
sc.install_pypi_package("pyahocorasick")
```

I am getting an error:

```
common.h:15:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory

   #include <Python.h>

            ^~~~~~~~~~

  compilation terminated.

  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

`pandas` installing without any problems.

I am getting the similar error when installing as a bootstrap action.

If I call:

```
%pip install pyahocorasick
```

it is installing fine, but I can not import it.

I tried this approach: [fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory, python-Levenshtein install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60509336/fatal-error-python-h-no-such-file-or-directory-python-levenshtein-install)

But I can not find any way to run `sudo` from the notebook.

**Edit:**

I tried to install `gcc` on bootstrape stage with the following `.sh` file called:

```
sudo yum -y install gcc
sudo yum -y install python3-devel
sudo pip3 install pyahocorasick --user
```

It doesn't help - I still getting error when call `import ahocorasick`

Comment: Even if you had sudo access, I doubt `yum install` would be available, or work as expected. You'd likely have to modify the AMI for the EMR cluster to bring `python-devel`

Comment: @OneCricketeer could you please advice - which AMI should I use as a base AMI ?

Comment: I'm saying you might need to make your own, not one publicly available, otherwise the bootstrap script should work too, but is slower

Comment: @OneCricketeer Yes, I understand. I just tried to create AMI based on ami-0742b4e673072066f (standard Amazon Linux 2 AMI (HVM), SSD Volume Type). I successfully installed `gcc` and `python-devel`. But it doesn't work with Spark

Comment: Same error as before? And I assume you mean it doesn't work with your pypi installations because Spark itself doesn't need gcc or Python development packages

Comment: @OneCricketeer thanks, it works. My mistake was that I installed the package to python 2 instead of python 3

Comment: Hmm. `pip3 install` wouldn't have done that, so I assume you mean pyspark was using Python2?

Comment: @OneCricketeer No - initially I created AMI with `pip install pyahocorasick`. It doesn't work. But it works with `pip3 install pyahocorasick`