# Trouble installing turbodbc

Tags: python, sql-server, linux, pip

I am attempting to install turbodbc on my Ubuntu 20.10 machine.
My specs are as follows: pip 20.2.4, Python 3.8.5 , gcc (Ubuntu 10.2.0-13ubuntu1) 10.2.0

I have attempted the solutions provided in the previous posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11094718/error-command-gcc-failed-with-exit-status-1-while-installing-eventlet) and and [here](https://github.com/stan-dev/pystan/issues/470).

I am getting this error message

```
(base) sean@sean-pc:~$ pip3 install turbodbc
Collecting turbodbc
  Using cached turbodbc-4.1.1.tar.gz (77 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: pybind11>=2.2.0 in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from turbodbc) (2.6.1)
Building wheels for collected packages: turbodbc
  Building wheel for turbodbc (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /home/sean/anaconda3/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-gv1ioaxx/turbodbc/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-gv1ioaxx/turbodbc/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-_e2ucudk
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-gv1ioaxx/turbodbc/
  Complete output (50 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/turbodbc
  copying turbodbc/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/turbodbc
  copying turbodbc/exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/turbodbc
  copying turbodbc/connect.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/turbodbc
  copying turbodbc/options.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/turbodbc
  copying turbodbc/cursor.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/turbodbc
  copying turbodbc/api_constants.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/turbodbc
  copying turbodbc/data_types.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/turbodbc
  copying turbodbc/constructors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/turbodbc
  copying turbodbc/connection.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/turbodbc
  running egg_info
  writing turbodbc.egg-info/PKG-INFO
  writing dependency_links to turbodbc.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
  writing requirements to turbodbc.egg-info/requires.txt
  writing top-level names to turbodbc.egg-info/top_level.txt
  reading manifest file 'turbodbc.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
  writing manifest file 'turbodbc.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  running build_ext
  building 'libturbodbc' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/src
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/src/cpp_odbc
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/src/cpp_odbc/level2
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/src/cpp_odbc/level1
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/src/cpp_odbc/level3
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/src/turbodbc
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/src/turbodbc/field_translators
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/src/turbodbc/result_sets
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/src/turbodbc/descriptions
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/src/turbodbc/parameter_sets
  gcc -pthread -B /home/sean/anaconda3/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -Iinclude/ -I/home/sean/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pybind11/include -I/home/sean/anaconda3/include/python3.8 -c src/cpp_odbc/connection.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/src/cpp_odbc/connection.o --std=c++11
  gcc -pthread -B /home/sean/anaconda3/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -Iinclude/ -I/home/sean/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pybind11/include -I/home/sean/anaconda3/include/python3.8 -c src/cpp_odbc/column_description.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/src/cpp_odbc/column_description.o --std=c++11
  gcc -pthread -B /home/sean/anaconda3/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -Iinclude/ -I/home/sean/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pybind11/include -I/home/sean/anaconda3/include/python3.8 -c src/cpp_odbc/environment.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/src/cpp_odbc/environment.o --std=c++11
  gcc -pthread -B /home/sean/anaconda3/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -Iinclude/ -I/home/sean/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pybind11/include -I/home/sean/anaconda3/include/python3.8 -c src/cpp_odbc/error.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/src/cpp_odbc/error.o --std=c++11
  gcc -pthread -B /home/sean/anaconda3/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -Iinclude/ -I/home/sean/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pybind11/include -I/home/sean/anaconda3/include/python3.8 -c src/cpp_odbc/multi_value_buffer.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/src/cpp_odbc/multi_value_buffer.o --std=c++11
  gcc -pthread -B /home/sean/anaconda3/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -Iinclude/ -I/home/sean/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pybind11/include -I/home/sean/anaconda3/include/python3.8 -c src/cpp_odbc/make_environment.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/src/cpp_odbc/make_environment.o --std=c++11
  gcc -pthread -B /home/sean/anaconda3/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -Iinclude/ -I/home/sean/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pybind11/include -I/home/sean/anaconda3/include/python3.8 -c src/cpp_odbc/cpp_odbc.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/src/cpp_odbc/cpp_odbc.o --std=c++11
  gcc -pthread -B /home/sean/anaconda3/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -Iinclude/ -I/home/sean/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pybind11/include -I/home/sean/anaconda3/include/python3.8 -c src/cpp_odbc/statement.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/src/cpp_odbc/statement.o --std=c++11
  gcc -pthread -B /home/sean/anaconda3/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -Iinclude/ -I/home/sean/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pybind11/include -I/home/sean/anaconda3/include/python3.8 -c src/cpp_odbc/level2/level1_connector.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/src/cpp_odbc/level2/level1_connector.o --std=c++11
  src/cpp_odbc/level2/level1_connector.cpp:17:10: fatal error: boost/locale.hpp: No such file or directory
     17 | #include <boost/locale.hpp>
        |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  compilation terminated.
  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for turbodbc
  Running setup.py clean for turbodbc
Failed to build turbodbc
Installing collected packages: turbodbc
    Running setup.py install for turbodbc ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /home/sean/anaconda3/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-gv1ioaxx/turbodbc/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-gv1ioaxx/turbodbc/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-_el_y_vc/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/sean/anaconda3/include/python3.8/turbodbc
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-gv1ioaxx/turbodbc/
    Complete output (50 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/turbodbc
    copying turbodbc/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/turbodbc
    copying turbodbc/exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/turbodbc
    copying turbodbc/connect.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/turbodbc
    copying turbodbc/options.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/turbodbc
    copying turbodbc/cursor.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/turbodbc
    copying turbodbc/api_constants.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/turbodbc
    copying turbodbc/data_types.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/turbodbc
    copying turbodbc/constructors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/turbodbc
    copying turbodbc/connection.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/turbodbc
    running egg_info
    writing turbodbc.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to turbodbc.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing requirements to turbodbc.egg-info/requires.txt
    writing top-level names to turbodbc.egg-info/top_level.txt
    reading manifest file 'turbodbc.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    writing manifest file 'turbodbc.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    running build_ext
    building 'libturbodbc' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/src
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/src/cpp_odbc
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/src/cpp_odbc/level2
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/src/cpp_odbc/level1
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/src/cpp_odbc/level3
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/src/turbodbc
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/src/turbodbc/field_translators
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/src/turbodbc/result_sets
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/src/turbodbc/descriptions
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/src/turbodbc/parameter_sets
    gcc -pthread -B /home/sean/anaconda3/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -Iinclude/ -I/home/sean/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pybind11/include -I/home/sean/anaconda3/include/python3.8 -c src/cpp_odbc/connection.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/src/cpp_odbc/connection.o --std=c++11
    gcc -pthread -B /home/sean/anaconda3/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -Iinclude/ -I/home/sean/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pybind11/include -I/home/sean/anaconda3/include/python3.8 -c src/cpp_odbc/column_description.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/src/cpp_odbc/column_description.o --std=c++11
    gcc -pthread -B /home/sean/anaconda3/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -Iinclude/ -I/home/sean/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pybind11/include -I/home/sean/anaconda3/include/python3.8 -c src/cpp_odbc/environment.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/src/cpp_odbc/environment.o --std=c++11
    gcc -pthread -B /home/sean/anaconda3/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -Iinclude/ -I/home/sean/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pybind11/include -I/home/sean/anaconda3/include/python3.8 -c src/cpp_odbc/error.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/src/cpp_odbc/error.o --std=c++11
    gcc -pthread -B /home/sean/anaconda3/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -Iinclude/ -I/home/sean/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pybind11/include -I/home/sean/anaconda3/include/python3.8 -c src/cpp_odbc/multi_value_buffer.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/src/cpp_odbc/multi_value_buffer.o --std=c++11
    gcc -pthread -B /home/sean/anaconda3/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -Iinclude/ -I/home/sean/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pybind11/include -I/home/sean/anaconda3/include/python3.8 -c src/cpp_odbc/make_environment.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/src/cpp_odbc/make_environment.o --std=c++11
    gcc -pthread -B /home/sean/anaconda3/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -Iinclude/ -I/home/sean/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pybind11/include -I/home/sean/anaconda3/include/python3.8 -c src/cpp_odbc/cpp_odbc.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/src/cpp_odbc/cpp_odbc.o --std=c++11
    gcc -pthread -B /home/sean/anaconda3/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -Iinclude/ -I/home/sean/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pybind11/include -I/home/sean/anaconda3/include/python3.8 -c src/cpp_odbc/statement.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/src/cpp_odbc/statement.o --std=c++11
    gcc -pthread -B /home/sean/anaconda3/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -Iinclude/ -I/home/sean/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pybind11/include -I/home/sean/anaconda3/include/python3.8 -c src/cpp_odbc/level2/level1_connector.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/src/cpp_odbc/level2/level1_connector.o --std=c++11
    src/cpp_odbc/level2/level1_connector.cpp:17:10: fatal error: boost/locale.hpp: No such file or directory
       17 | #include <boost/locale.hpp>
          |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /home/sean/anaconda3/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-gv1ioaxx/turbodbc/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-gv1ioaxx/turbodbc/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-_el_y_vc/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/sean/anaconda3/include/python3.8/turbodbc Check the logs for full command output.
```

I have gcc on my system and the gcc command works when I use it in the terminal. I am not sure what to do to fix this.

My pip list is as follows if that might help anyone

```
Package                            Version
---------------------------------- -------------------
alabaster                          0.7.12
anaconda-client                    1.7.2
anaconda-navigator                 1.10.0
anaconda-project                   0.8.3
argh                               0.26.2
argon2-cffi                        20.1.0
asn1crypto                         1.4.0
astroid                            2.4.2
astropy                            4.0.2
async-generator                    1.10
atomicwrites                       1.4.0
attrs                              20.3.0
autopep8                           1.5.4
azure-core                         1.9.0
azure-storage-blob                 12.5.0
Babel                              2.8.1
backcall                           0.2.0
backports.functools-lru-cache      1.6.1
backports.shutil-get-terminal-size 1.0.0
backports.tempfile                 1.0
backports.weakref                  1.0.post1
beautifulsoup4                     4.9.3
bitarray                           1.6.1
bkcharts                           0.2
bleach                             3.2.1
bokeh                              2.2.3
boto                               2.49.0
boto3                              1.16.10
botocore                           1.19.44
Bottleneck                         1.3.2
brotlipy                           0.7.0
cachetools                         4.2.0
cachey                             0.2.1
cairocffi                          1.2.0
CairoSVG                           2.5.0
certifi                            2020.6.20
cffi                               1.14.4
chardet                            3.0.4
click                              7.1.2
cloudpickle                        1.6.0
clyent                             1.2.2
colorama                           0.4.4
conda                              4.9.2
conda-build                        3.20.5
conda-package-handling             1.7.2
conda-verify                       3.4.2
contextlib2                        0.6.0.post1
convertdate                        2.2.0
cryptography                       3.1.1
cssselect2                         0.4.1
cycler                             0.10.0
Cython                             0.29.21
cytoolz                            0.11.0
dask                               2.30.0
decorator                          4.4.2
defusedxml                         0.6.0
diff-match-patch                   20200713
dill                               0.3.3
distributed                        2.30.1
docutils                           0.16
entrypoints                        0.3
et-xmlfile                         1.0.1
fastcache                          1.1.0
filelock                           3.0.12
flake8                             3.8.4
Flask                              1.1.2
Flask-Cors                         3.0.10
Flask-SQLAlchemy                   2.4.4
flatbuffers                        1.12
fsspec                             0.8.4
future                             0.18.2
gast                               0.3.3
gcsfs                              0.6.2
gensim                             3.8.3
gevent                             20.9.0
glob2                              0.7
gmpy2                              2.0.8
google-api-core                    1.24.1
google-auth                        1.24.0
google-auth-oauthlib               0.4.2
google-cloud-core                  1.5.0
google-cloud-storage               1.35.0
google-crc32c                      1.1.0
google-pasta                       0.2.0
google-resumable-media             1.2.0
googleapis-common-protos           1.52.0
greenlet                           0.4.17
grpcio                             1.32.0
h5py                               2.10.0
hdbscan                            0.8.26
HeapDict                           1.0.1
holidays                           0.10.4
html5lib                           1.1
hub                                1.0.8
idna                               2.10
imageio                            2.9.0
imagesize                          1.2.0
importlib-metadata                 2.0.0
iniconfig                          1.1.1
intervaltree                       3.1.0
ipykernel                          5.4.2
ipython                            7.19.0
ipython-genutils                   0.2.0
ipywidgets                         7.6.2
isodate                            0.6.0
isort                              5.6.4
itsdangerous                       1.1.0
jdcal                              1.4.1
jedi                               0.18.0
jeepney                            0.5.0
Jinja2                             2.11.2
jmespath                           0.10.0
joblib                             1.0.0
json5                              0.9.5
jsonschema                         3.2.0
jupyter                            1.0.0
jupyter-client                     6.1.7
jupyter-console                    6.2.0
jupyter-core                       4.7.0
jupyterlab                         2.2.6
jupyterlab-pygments                0.1.2
jupyterlab-server                  1.2.0
jupyterlab-widgets                 1.0.0
Keras-Preprocessing                1.1.2
keyring                            21.4.0
kiwisolver                         1.3.1
kneed                              0.7.0
korean-lunar-calendar              0.2.1
lazy-object-proxy                  1.4.3
libarchive-c                       2.9
littleutils                        0.2.2
llvmlite                           0.34.0
lmdb                               1.0.0
locket                             0.2.0
lxml                               4.6.1
lz4                                3.1.1
Markdown                           3.3.3
MarkupSafe                         1.1.1
matplotlib                         3.3.3
mccabe                             0.6.1
mistune                            0.8.4
mkl-fft                            1.2.0
mkl-random                         1.1.1
mkl-service                        2.3.0
mock                               4.0.2
more-itertools                     8.6.0
mpmath                             1.1.0
msgpack                            1.0.0
msrest                             0.6.19
multipledispatch                   0.6.0
multiprocess                       0.70.11.1
navigator-updater                  0.2.1
nbclient                           0.5.1
nbconvert                          6.0.7
nbformat                           5.0.8
nest-asyncio                       1.4.3
networkx                           2.5
nltk                               3.5
nose                               1.3.7
notebook                           6.1.6
numba                              0.51.2
numcodecs                          0.7.2
numexpr                            2.7.1
numpy                              1.19.4
numpydoc                           1.1.0
olefile                            0.46
openpyxl                           3.0.5
opt-einsum                         3.3.0
outdated                           0.2.0
packaging                          20.8
pandas                             1.2.0
pandocfilters                      1.4.3
parso                              0.8.1
partd                              1.1.0
path                               15.0.0
pathlib2                           2.3.5
pathos                             0.2.7
pathtools                          0.1.2
patsy                              0.5.1
pep8                               1.7.1
pexpect                            4.8.0
pickleshare                        0.7.5
Pillow                             8.0.1
pip                                20.2.4
pkginfo                            1.6.1
plotly                             4.14.1
pluggy                             0.13.1
ply                                3.11
pox                                0.2.9
ppft                               1.6.6.3
prometheus-client                  0.9.0
prompt-toolkit                     3.0.8
psutil                             5.8.0
ptyprocess                         0.7.0
py                                 1.9.0
pyasn1                             0.4.8
pyasn1-modules                     0.2.8
pybind11                           2.6.1
pycodestyle                        2.6.0
pycosat                            0.6.3
pycparser                          2.20
pycurl                             7.43.0.6
pydocstyle                         5.1.1
pyflakes                           2.2.0
Pygments                           2.7.3
pylint                             2.6.0
PyMeeus                            0.3.7
pyodbc                             4.0.30
pyOpenSSL                          19.1.0
pyparsing                          2.4.7
Pyphen                             0.10.0
pyrsistent                         0.17.3
PySocks                            1.7.1
pytest                             0.0.0
python-dateutil                    2.8.1
python-jsonrpc-server              0.4.0
python-language-server             0.35.1
pytz                               2019.3
PyWavelets                         1.1.1
pyxdg                              0.27
PyYAML                             5.3.1
pyzmq                              20.0.0
QDarkStyle                         2.8.1
QtAwesome                          1.0.1
qtconsole                          5.0.1
QtPy                               1.9.0
regex                              2020.11.13
requests                           2.24.0
requests-oauthlib                  1.3.0
retrying                           1.3.3
rope                               0.18.0
rsa                                4.6
Rtree                              0.9.4
ruamel-yaml                        0.15.87
s3fs                               0.4.2
s3transfer                         0.3.3
scikit-image                       0.18.1
scikit-learn                       0.24.0
scipy                              1.5.4
seaborn                            0.11.1
SecretStorage                      3.1.2
Send2Trash                         1.5.0
setuptools                         50.3.1.post20201107
simplegeneric                      0.8.1
singledispatch                     3.4.0.3
sip                                4.19.13
six                                1.15.0
sklearn                            0.0
smart-open                         4.1.0
snowballstemmer                    2.0.0
sortedcollections                  1.2.1
sortedcontainers                   2.2.2
soupsieve                          2.0.1
Sphinx                             3.2.1
sphinxcontrib-applehelp            1.0.2
sphinxcontrib-devhelp              1.0.2
sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp             1.0.3
sphinxcontrib-jsmath               1.0.1
sphinxcontrib-qthelp               1.0.3
sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml      1.1.4
sphinxcontrib-websupport           1.2.4
spyder                             4.1.5
spyder-kernels                     1.9.4
SQLAlchemy                         1.3.22
SQLAlchemy-serializer              1.3.4.4
statsmodels                        0.12.0
sympy                              1.6.2
tables                             3.6.1
tblib                              1.7.0
tensorboard                        2.4.0
tensorboard-plugin-wit             1.7.0
tensorflow                         2.4.0
tensorflow-estimator               2.4.0
tensorflow-hub                     0.10.0
termcolor                          1.1.0
terminado                          0.9.1
testpath                           0.4.4
textblob                           0.15.3
threadpoolctl                      2.1.0
tifffile                           2020.12.8
tinycss2                           1.1.0
toml                               0.10.2
toolz                              0.11.1
tornado                            6.1
tqdm                               4.51.0
traitlets                          5.0.5
typing-extensions                  3.7.4.3
ujson                              4.0.1
unicodecsv                         0.14.1
urllib3                            1.25.11
waitress                           1.4.4
watchdog                           0.10.3
wcwidth                            0.2.5
WeasyPrint                         52.2
webencodings                       0.5.1
Werkzeug                           1.0.1
wheel                              0.36.2
widgetsnbextension                 3.5.1
wrapt                              1.12.1
wurlitzer                          2.0.1
xlrd                               1.2.0
XlsxWriter                         1.3.7
xlwt                               1.3.0
xmltodict                          0.12.0
yapf                               0.30.0
zarr                               2.5.0
zict                               2.0.0
zipp                               3.4.0
zope.event                         4.5.0
zope.interface                     5.1.2
```

Comment: https://turbodbc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/getting_started.html#linux-and-osx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boost is not installed.
You can try this

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-locale-dev
```

Or install all boost libs

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are using an anaconda environment.

You can install using the `conda` command to avoid dependency and build tools problems. anaconda manages it on its own.

Please follow the following command

`conda install -c conda-forge turbodbc`