# Installation errors with Brownie python on MacOS

Tags: python, macos, pip

I am having an issue with installing `eth-brownie` on my MacOS. I updated everything in the dedicated virtual environment, but installation fails because of these packages:

- bitarray
- cytoolz
- lru-dict

I tried installing directly via the .whl file, but got the same error.

I am a bit reluctant to install Xcode as it is >15Go

```
(blockchain) bash-3.2$ pipx install eth-brownie --verbose
pipx >(setup:717): pipx version is 0.16.3
pipx >(setup:718): Default python interpreter is '/Users/myname/anaconda3/envs/blockchain/bin/python3'
pipx >(package_name_from_spec:323): Determined package name: eth-brownie
pipx >(package_name_from_spec:324): Package name determined in 0.0s
creating virtual environment...
pipx >(run_subprocess:135): running /Users/myname/anaconda3/envs/blockchain/bin/python3 -m venv --without-pip /Users/
pipx >(analyze_pip_output:261): pip failed to build packages:
    bitarray
    cytoolz
    lru-dict
```

Some possibly relevant errors from pip install:

```
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), 
missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52558100/11969592

Try running the following:

After installing [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) run:

`brew install gcc`

`export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH`

It looks like you'll just need `gcc` installed